# Spring Data Repository (JPA) - findByXXX using entity relation

Tags: java, spring

A Schedule entity has a one to one relationship with a Market entity as well as some other "simple" properties.

Here is my ScheduleRepository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "schedule")
public interface ScheduleRepository extends JpaRepository<Schedule, Long>
{
    Collection<Schedule> findByMarket(Market market);
}
```

"findByMarket" method works fine when invoking the method programmatically. However, when invoking directly from a web application (http://localhost:8080/schedule/search/findByMarket), the request type must be GET.

My question is how do I pass a Market JSON object using GET? Using POST wouldn't be an issues but findXxx methods must use GET. I tried passing something like:

```
?market={marketId:60}
```

in the querystring but to no avail.

Comment: Why not use Plain Old GET Parameters? `?marketId=60`

Comment: It cannot convert it to a Market instance and if I name the finder "findByMarketId(int marketId)" the compiler will complain.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what your controller looks like, I would assume that if you wanted to pass marketId on a get it would look like.

?marketId=60

And your method would look like.  The method you use will handle converting to and from JSON.

```
@Get
@Path("/query")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public Todo whatEverNameYouLike(@PathParam("marketId") String marketId)
```

Comment: I am using @RepositoryRestResource so I won't have to code a controller.

Comment: I ended up using a @Query annotation, like jdepedro suggested:

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation it is referenced to use the `@Param` annotation, so you can call to your rest service giving a query parameter. [Here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/) you have an example:

```
package hello;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {

    List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

Comment: Using a primitive or any other "simple" object such as string is not an issue. However, since the parameter is a Market object, it complains it cannot convert a string to that type.

Comment: And you can not modify the findBy using a @Query annotation, so you can search via the simple id?

Comment: Haven't tried that yet, but I prefer solving the issue without any annotation. The main issue being how/what JSON to pass from the browser using GET.

Comment: This is not allowed by definition of Http. GET is a request that can receive parameters via Headers, parameters in the url (called query parameters), but never has a body (where it is placed the json). I don't think that Spring is prepared to link the json to its repo.

Comment: If that is the case, the compiler should have been smart enough to give an error. Theoretically, I was thinking about a querystring such as ?market={marketId:60} or something along that lines. Though someone else must have encountered this issue before and hopefully know if this is just the way it is or whether there is an elegant solution.

Comment: This kind of queryString is kind of weird. Not sure if Jackson processes it (Spring uses Jackson unless you specify something different). I encourage you to proceed with a parameter and us a Spring data name like `findByMarketId(@Param("marketId") Integer id);`

Comment: Actually, I read the compiler error more carefully and ended up modifying the method to the following which works:

findByMarketMarketId(Integer marketId)

Comment: In this case, accept the post as valid response for other users. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a @Query annotation, like jdepedro suggested:

```
@Query("select s from Schedule s where s.market.marketId = :marketId and s.locale.localeId = :localeId and s.offline >= :offline order by s.placement, s.slot, s.online")
    Collection<Schedule> findByMarket(@Param("marketId") Integer marketId, @Param("localeId") Integer localeId, @Param("offline") Date offline);
```